# A substitute formula for MSE

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, mse

I don't understand where this formula for Mean Squared Error is coming from.

How do we arrive at:

$$MSE = \frac{1}{m}||y' - y||_2^2$$

from:

$$MSE = \frac{1}{m}\cdot\sum_i(y'_{i} - y_{i})^2$$

(The source is deeplearningbook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\|x\|_2=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$$

Hence $$\|x\|_2^2=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$

Now let $x=y'-y$ and you obtain your formula.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What is this $||x||_2$ called?

Comment: [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) or $2$-norm.

Comment: This is $l_2$ norm

Answer (score 1):

- Single bars refers to a vector norm: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorNorm.html
- Double bars refers to a matrix norm: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixNorm.html
- sub-scripted number refers the power that $x$ is being raised too

The Euclidean norm from above falls into this class and is the 2-norm, and the 1-norm is the norm that corresponds to the rectilinear distance.

Check out $L_p$ space (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) for info on the relations between norm spaces and a generalization of the p-norm for finite-dimensional vector spaces.